# httplib2.SSLHandshakeError - Google Cloud Storage Python application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, httplib2

We are trying to download the data transfer files from our bucket, using the python cloud storage sample application chunked_transfer.py available at the below link

https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform-samples/source/browse?repo=storage#git%252Ffile-transfer-json

But when i execute the application it fails with the below exception. please help me fix this, i need to fix this very fast...

```
Authenticating...
Constructing Google Cloud Storage service...
storage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chunked_transfer.py", line 216, in <module>
    download(sys.argv)
  File "chunked_transfer.py", line 172, in download
    service = get_authenticated_service(RO_SCOPE)
  File "chunked_transfer.py", line 104, in get_authenticated_service
    return discovery_build('storage', 'v1beta1', http=http)
  File "/home/z062743/Venky_Google/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/z062743/Venky_Google/apiclient/discovery.py", line 194, in build
   resp, content = http.request(requested_url)
  File "/home/z062743/Venky_Google/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/z062743/Venky_Google/oauth2client/client.py", line 490, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/home/z062743/Venky_Google/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1571, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/home/z062743/Venky_Google/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1318, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/home/z062743/Venky_Google/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1253, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/z062743/Venky_Google/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1045, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Comment: Did you properly configure the client_secrets.json file?

Comment: Can i know litte more information about what properly means.... I kept client_secret.json file in the directory where i placed my python application

Comment: Did you put  your client_id and client_secret in the json file?

Comment: Yes, i had put @Gwell

Answer (score 0):

this issue is resolved for us once we disabled the SSL security check off by our security team  over the network.